# concatenation of lines as a variable while comparing two files using awk

Tags: variables, awk

I am comparing two files using awk. Following is representation of first file (file1.txt):

```
1
15
MRUKLM
GHLKGM
BNUIOK
```

Following is representation of second file (file2.txt):

```
AGHLKMT
MFBGSJY
GSBDGLM
```

I want to compare two files based on certain patterns. Moreover, first line of the output file should contain the total number of lines in the second file followed by second and third line of the first file. Hence, the header of the output file should be as follows:

```
3(total lines of second file)
15(second line of first file)
MRUKLM(third line of first file)
certain pattern.....
certain pattern....
certain pattern....
```

I wrote the following codes:

```
vari=$(wc -l file2.txt)|awk -v lin="" 'NR==FNR{if(NR>1 && NR<4)lin=$lin$0;else a[NR]=$0;next}BEGIN{print vari,lin}match($0,/([0-9]*)_(.*)/,c){print a[2*c[1]+2];print a[2*c[1]+3]}' file1.txt file2.txt> output_file.txt
```

The part of the code that extract the pattern is working perfectly, however, I could not get any header in the output file. The output I get is as follows:

```
certain pattern....
certain pattern....
```

It turns out that I did some mistakes in assigning variables. Following are the updated codes:

```
awk -v vari="$(cat file2.txt|wc -l)" 'NR==FNR{if(NR>1 && NR<4)print $0;else a[NR]=$0;next}BEGIN{print vari}match($0,/([0-9]*)_(.*)/,c){print a[2*c[1]+2];print a[2*c[1]+3]}' file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

It is giving the desirable output.

Comment: this cannot work as written, your `vari` is not visible to `awk`! `$lin` is not the value of `lin` etc.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error! I just modified the code sucessfully!